# React component not firing onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I'm working through Tyler Mcginnis' React weather app tutorial and I'm stuck on step 9. I've set up an onClick event that is supposed to push a state and pathname on a route and redirect to the route.

When I click on the element, nothing happens. I try to console log the event but it isn't even firing.

I've set up my ForecastContainer like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var Forecast = require('../components/Forecast');
var weatherHelpers = require('../utils/weather');

var ForecastContainer = React.createClass({
   contextTypes: {
      router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },

  getInitialState: function(){
   return {
      isLoading: true,
      forecastData: {}
    }
  },

...

  handleClick: function(weather){
    this.context.router.push({
      pathname: '/detail/' + this.props.routeParams.city,
      state: {
        weather: weather
      }
    })
    console.log(weather)
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    window.clearInterval(this.interval)
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <Forecast
        city={this.props.routeParams.city}
        isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
        forecastData={this.state.forecastData}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      />
      )
  }
});

module.exports = ForecastContainer;
```

And I had written my own Forecast component before but had the same error. So I took Tyler's code and I'm still receiving the same no onClick action

His code is below:

```
function DayItem (props) {
  console.log('Day item', )
  var date = getDate(props.day.dt);
  var icon = props.day.weather[0].icon;
  return (
    <div style={styles.dayContainer}>
      <img style={styles.weather} src={'./app/images/weather-icons/' + icon + '.svg'} alt='Weather' />
      <h2 style={styles.subheader}>{date}</h2>
      <h1>{props.text}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

function ForecastUI (props) {

  return (
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
      <h1 style={styles.header}>{props.city}</h1>
      <p style={styles.subheader}>Select a day</p>
      <div style={styles.container}>
        {props.forecast.list.map(function (listItem) {
          return <DayItem key={listItem.dt} day={listItem} onClick= {props.onClick.bind(null, listItem)} />
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function Forecast (props) {
  console.log('Forecast', props)
  return (
    <div>
      {
        props.isLoading === true
          ? <h1 style={styles.header}> Loading </h1>
          : <ForecastUI city={props.city} forecast={props.forecastData} onClick={props.onClick}/>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm rendering the DayItem within ForecastUI and the props are passed in. But when I click on the element, nothing happens.

I've included the line in the routes file:

```
<Route path='detail/:city' component={DetailContainer} />
```

I'm not sure where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in DayItem seems to be clickable. Which element do you want to attach onClick to? Maybe the image, or the h1. Add it to the DayItem.

```
function DayItem (props) {
  console.log('Day item', )
  var date = getDate(props.day.dt);
  var icon = props.day.weather[0].icon;
  return (
    <div style={styles.dayContainer}>
      <img style={styles.weather} src={'./app/images/weather-icons/' + icon + '.svg'} alt='Weather' />
      <h2 style={styles.subheader}>{date}</h2>
      <h1>{props.text}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Add to the img:

```
      <img style={styles.weather} src={'./app/images/weather-icons/' + icon + '.svg'} alt='Weather' onClick={props.onClick} />
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just started doing a deep dive into ReactJS. I seem to miss the little details.